# Reading Excel File without using jar file

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I want to know whether it is possible to read data from MS Excel file without using any jar files in android? 
If it's possible then what's the best approach to do it .

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

It's entirely possible to code a complete Excel API to read (and write) an Excel file. But that takes time and a lot of energy, as these formats are huge and complicated. You are practically mirroring the functions of [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) or [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/). And these projects are huge.

As I don't know your reason for not using an external library (like an .jar) to read Excel, my answer is: Yes it's possible. Read the excel specification and implement an library to read this format. But practically: Don't do it and use the libraries from above. This will preserve you from a lot of pain.